# JavaScript Class Constructor and DOM (Updated)

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

I am new to programming, and I don't quite grasp the idea of utilizing class constructor in real life. For instance, let's just say I am trying to create a DOM event handler so I can take user input and push it into `CreateTodoList.todos` array.

```
class CreateTodoList {
  constructor(list) {
    this.todoList = list;
    this.todos = [];
  }
```

Then let's just assume that I have built `addTodo()` function which takes text parameter where an user enters her/his todo.

```
 addTodo(text) {
    this.todos.push(text);
    this.todoList.appendChild(CreateTodoList.addtoList(text));
  }
```

Here, `addtoList` creates DOM element that takes value of the user input.
This `addTodo` function, then pushes the text parameter into the array I made in constructor, while also calling `addtoList` that makes the DOM element.

Now, let's say I click on "add" button where it takes user input value.
I will build an event handler that responds to click which will add user input to the todoList.

```
CreateTodoList.eventHandler('click', (e) => {
  let userText.todos = document.querySelector(#userInput).value;
  addTodo(userText); 
})
```

I am trying to build an eventHandler here, so I can add user input to todoList, and have implemented this several times, but had no luck but receiving reference error.

Below is my full code.

```
/** @format */
const add = document.querySelector('#btn_add');
let addInput = document.querySelector('#add');
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
class CreateTodoList {
  constructor(list) {
    this.todoList = list;
    this.todos = [];
  }


  addtoList(text) {
    let checkboxEl = document.createElement('span');
    checkboxEl.classList.add('round');
    let checkboxEl2 = document.createElement('input');
    checkboxEl2.id = 'checkbox';
    checkboxEl2.type = 'checkbox';
    let checkboxEl3 = document.createElement('label');
    checkboxEl3.htmlFor = 'checkbox';
    checkboxEl.appendChild(checkboxEl2);
    checkboxEl.appendChild(checkboxEl3);

    let todoTextEl = document.createElement('input');
    todoTextEl.value = text;
    todoTextEl.disabled = true;
    todoTextEl.classList.add('edit_input');
    todoTextEl.id = 'edit_input';
    todoTextEl.type = 'text';
    todoTextEl.name = 'edit_input';
    let todoTextEl2 = document.createElement('label');
    todoTextEl2.htmlFor = 'edit_input';

    let editEl = document.createElement('i');
    editEl.classList.add('far');
    editEl.classList.add('fa-edit');

    let deleteEl = document.createElement('i');
    deleteEl.classList.add('far');
    deleteEl.classList.add('fa-trash-alt');

    let dateEl = document.createElement('small');
    dateEl.textContent = timeago.format(new Date());

    let liEl = document.createElement('li');
    liEl.appendChild(checkboxEl);
    liEl.appendChild(todoTextEl);
    liEl.appendChild(todoTextEl2);
    liEl.appendChild(editEl);
    liEl.appendChild(deleteEl);
    liEl.appendChild(dateEl);

    let list = document.querySelector('ul');
    list.appendChild(li);

    return liEl;
  }

  removeFromList(text) {
    let list = document.querySelector('ul');
    let childs = Array.from(list.childNodes);
    let removable = child.find((i) => i.innerText === text);
    return item;
  }

  //todos 배열(todo 데이터에) text를 추가한다.
  //todoList 에 liEL(리스트 엘레먼트) 를 append 한다.
  addTodo(text) {
    this.todos.push(text);
    this.todoList.appendChild(CreateTodoList.addtoList(text));
  }

  removeTodo(text) {
    let removed = this.todos.filter((el) => el !== text);
    todo.todoList.removeChild(CreateTodoList.removeFromList(text));
    this.todos = removed;
  }

  
  get getList() {
    return this.todos;
  }
}

class Handlers {}
```

Comment: Is there a static `CreateTodoList.eventHandler` method? And where are you creating an instance of your class, i.e.  `new CreateTodoList(…)`? Please post the full code.

Comment: Think of classes like a blueprint, the *objects* are the houses. When you build or *construct* a house you can add, remove or change things. The  Same applies with classes, I highly recommend you take a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#:~:text=Classes%20are%20a%20template%20for,shared%20with%20ES5%20classalike%20semantics.

Comment: Abstract questions like this are not really appropriate for SO. Try to implement your approach, and if you can't get it working post the code and we'll help you then.

Comment: If the code you have works, and you're willing to share all of it, you can check the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/) to see if this question is on-topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: But in geneal, if you're not creating instances of the class, classes may not be appropriate for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. What I am trying to do here is to understand OOP through the simplest app I can understand. I have read class on mdn, and was thinking if users can put in data and I can process those data through constructor to create new array. I'd appreciate if you could give me directional advise as far as building todo app and apply class&OOP method.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Where are you calling `new CreateTodoList`, where are you using `add`, `addInput` and `form`?

Comment: new CreateTodoList is the part I can't quite understand. I understand i can statically create CreateTodoList, by simply typing let todo1 = new CreateTodoList('Ride Bicycle"). But basically I want this to take user input from web client then process this into todos array. The variable I called above has no usage. I just thought it'd be convenient to call them and maybe use it later.

Comment: @paul.kim1901 The parameter of your constructor expects the DOM element in which the list should be shown, not a string. That's what I was missing. Yes, you typically will create on such global static variable, unless you plan to show many different todo lists on the same page.

Comment: @paul.kim1901 And regarding the dynamic input, with all the methods that you have already written, it's really just `add.addEventListener('click', e => { todo1.addTodo(addInput.value); });` (Or maybe a submit handler on your form that contains the input and the button, but since you haven't shown your page markup I cannot tell)

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for your explanation. I've just implemented it and see it working! Another question if you don't mind. Yes, my code seems more organized compared to just throwing bunch of call back functions like I did before, but is there a particular reason I should be using class to process user inputs versus conventional codes, like writing functions in order, let's say.

Comment: Yes, using object-oriented code definitely helps since you aggregate the `todoList` and the `todos` in a structure, and have methods to interact with them on there as well. You don't necessarily need to use `class` syntax to achieve that, though.

Comment: @Bergi If using conventional OOP syntax like creating object literal to store methods or variables as property achieves the same result as Class, is there any particular reason to use Class over regular object structure?

Comment: @paul.kim1901 More familiar syntax for programmers coming from class-based languages, and better performance if you created a (really huge) lot of instances. Both of which are probably irrelevant in your case.